# DATETIME EQUALITY: SQL to Javascript

Tags: sql, datetime, asp-classic

I would like to compare two dates in javascript.  One date is from SQL server in DATETIME format (i.e.: '2008-02-22 10:45:12.000') as a STRING.  The second is from html (getelementbyid) in the format of '1/10/2014 4:20 PM'.  I just need to know if one is greater than the other but I am coming into problems converting to usable datatypes.

The SQL date is coming to the javascript using response.write (ASP written within the js)

Any pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Converting the date/times into seconds will allow you to compare them

Comment: From the question "...  I am coming into problems converting to usable datatypes ..."  So OP knows he/she needs to convert the values.  I don't see what your answer adds to his/her knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Javascript is terrible at dealing with dates and times.  Lots of people have wasted lots of time trying to get it to do things that it can't.

I think you should look into using some kind of Javascript library for date processing.  One option is [**moment.js**](http://momentjs.com) which can do all sorts of date and time conversion, from one format to another.  It seems to be exactly what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

In javascript converting to seconds since 1970, jan 1st

```
 var jsTimeInSecs = new Date().getTime() / 1000;
```

in ASP:

```
 d = cdate("2008-08-22 10:45:12.000")
 unixSecs = datediff(s, "1970/1/1", d)
```

Now bring the unixSecs from ASP to javascript:

```
response.write "<script>var aspTimeInSecs = " & clng(unixSecs) & ";"
```

So there you go, ready to compare the aspTimeInSecs and the jsTimeInSecs